# Does Aura of Invulnerability protect against spell attacks that are not delivered by casting a spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, attack, aura

A [hollyphant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/hollyphant) projects an Aura of Invulnerability, that protects it from spells. Dreb, a [barbed devil](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/barbed-devil), attacks the hollyphant using its Hurl Flame action, which is a Ranged Spell Attack. Can the flame hit and damage the hollyphant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Hurl Flame is not a spell of 5th level or lower.

Aura of Invulnerability says:

> **Any spell of 5th level or lower** cast from outside the barrier can’t affect creatures or objects within it

Hurl Flame is not a spell of 5th level or lower, so it ignores Hollyphant's aura.

The *Sage Advice Compendium* clarifies that it is intentional that spell attacks are not always made by casting a spell, in the context of opportunity attacks being made with melee spell attacks:

> A few monsters can make opportunity attacks with melee spell attacks. Here’s how: certain monsters—including the banshee, the lich, and the specter—have a melee spell attack *that isn’t delivered by a spell. For example, the banshee’s Corrupting Touch action is a melee spell attack but no spell is cast to make it*. The banshee can, therefore, make opportunity attacks with Corrupting Touch.